# Autosys - complex scenario

Tags: autosys

Need to achieve scenario where ABC  job is depend on 123_J & 456_J
where 123_J holiday calendar have 15 days
and 456_J holiday calendar have 9 days

job runs at 04-05:00 AM ET of BUS_DT : Today -1  Day :Tuesday - Saturday
eg : Sep 6th Holiday for both 123_J & 456_J
Sep7th holiday for 123_J alone whereas 456_J will run  no issues

in order to start ABC Job both 123_J & 456 should be available of same BUS_DT
even though 123_J is not loaded on July 7th  both 123_J & 456_J have same Bus_DT..

how to enable the condition in such away ABC job should  run on 7th  even there is holiday for 123_J   not holiday for 456_J

this above scenario is of Monday being holiday and tuesday being  holiday for 123_J

In  normal schedule apart from holidays both 123_J & 456_J runs on latest completion job will be triggered ..

show to achieve this scenario  in holiday & Normal schedule ?

Comment: using standard holiday calendar for 123_J & 456_J

Comment: can we do with help of global variable since it is head and toss situation ?

Comment: @Piyush can you please help me on this ?